# Small product images for Cloud Zoom in Magento?

Tags: jquery, magento

Small product images seem to have a problem with the Cloud Zoom extension in Magento.

Please see [this page](http://www.princessly.com/ball-gown-strapless-dropped-waist-sleeveless-floor-length-chapel-train-wedding-dress.html) for example. The Cloud Zoom extension is filling the Zoom View window with the image rather than leaving it blank.

So my question, is there any way to make the Cloud Zoom extension to leave blank when the original image is smaller than the Zoom View area?

Thanks!

Comment: create a jquery function which it should be get image width and height than compare viewable area dimension. if its smaller than area don't use cloud zoom. Contrast, use Cloud Zoom function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is easy. Just add 2 more CSS styles for .cloud-zoom-big:

```
.cloud-zoom-big {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color:#fff;
}
```